# How to edit response body returned by VCR gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vcr

I'm using VCR to record responses from other systems that i'm integrating with.

But, this response get a huge JSON an VCR is saving it in a binary format:

```
body:
  encoding: ASCII-8BIT
  string: !binary |-
    eyJsaXN0IjpbXSwiZmFjZXRzIjpbeyJuYW1lIjoiU2FsZXNDaGFubmVsTmFt
    ZSIsInR5cGUiOi...
```

Is there a way where I can save ONLY the response body as JSON?

I want to do this to edit the returned JSON in order to make other scenarios for my tests,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking in VCR [google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vcr-ruby/cS07APv-p50), I was told to do my own serializer in order to get a pretty json return.

So, i've found this [code](https://github.com/mislav/movieapp/blob/master/spec/support/vcr.rb). With some minor modifications, it solved my problem, formatting the response body to not be encoded as binary.

Comment: To be clear, the only modification I had to make was to remove the filter_sensitive_data parts, and it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

From the [google forum link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vcr-ruby/cS07APv-p50) that Cleyton supplied (I would leave a comment if I had the rep), the following change in `spec_helper.rb` works for me:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.before_record do |i|
    i.response.body.force_encoding('UTF-8')
  end
end
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. I guess it's b/c vcr falls back to binary when unicode symbol is in response and ascii encoding is used

Answer (score 5):

Use `decode_compressed_response` in your configuration.

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.default_cassette_options = { :decode_compressed_response => true } 
end
```

Comment: I am using VCR 5.0.0 with this option, but still end up with binary code in my recordings. My options are set to `{ serialize_with: :yaml,
                                  record: :once,
                                  allow_playback_repeats: true,
                                  decode_compressed_response: true }`